# Use setWindowModified() on QTabWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtabwidget

Because `QTabWidget` inherits `QWidget` we have `setWindowModified()` available.
But it seems it doesn't work for the tab title:

```
ui->tab1->setWindowTitle(QString("%1[*]").arg(tr("Tab title")));
ui->tab1->setWindowModified(true);
```

but it doesn't show the '*' nor changes the tab text.
Is there a way to handle this automatically instead of manually use `setTabText()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to get the tab text to follow the widget title by default.  Having said that, it should be very easy to fix up by overriding [`QTabWidget::tabInserted`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#tabInserted).

```
class tab_widget: public QTabWidget {
  using super      = QTabWidget;
  using this_class = tab_widget;
public:
  using super::super;
protected:
  virtual void tabInserted (int index) override
    {
      super::tabInserted(index);
      if (auto *w = widget(index)) {
        connect(w, &QWidget::windowTitleChanged, this, &this_class::handle_window_title_change);
      }
    }
  virtual void tabRemoved (int index) override
    {
      super::tabRemoved(index);
      if (auto *w = widget(index)) {
        disconnect(w, &QWidget::windowTitleChanged, this, &this_class::handle_window_title_change);
      }
    }
private:
  void handle_window_title_change (const QString &title)
    {
      if (auto *w = qobject_cast<QWidget *>(sender())) {
        setTabText(indexOf(w), title);
      }
    }
};
```

Using the above class rather than `QTabWidget` should result in the tab text mirroring the title of the widget associated with that tab.